# Reference cell in another workbook as email address in .To field

Tags: excel, path, vba

I'm trying to reference cell A1 in another workbook, in a certain sheet, to be set as the "To" field in an email. Here is my code:

```
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

Addresses = Workbooks("Test.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1").Value

On Error Resume Next
With OutMail

.to = Addresses
.CC = ""
.BCC = ""
.Subject = "Confirm " & Format(Date, "mm.dd.yy")
.body = "Please see attached for your confirm.  Thanks,"
.Attachments.add ActiveWorkbook.FullName
.Display
End With
On Error GoTo 0

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing
```

When I execute the macro, the "To" field in the email has nothing in it. The cell I am referencing definitely has a value in it. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: When you run the code in the debugger, does `Addresses` get the intended value?

Comment: Don't use `On Error Resume Next` like that. It might be masking issues.

Comment: Nothing happens when I run the macro; no bugs.  All that happens is the addresses do not appear in the To: field in the email

Answer (score 1):

Try moving `display` to the beginning.  So...

```
With OutMail

    .display
```

Comment: Nice catch. @user2611396, since this answered your question,  please accept it by clicking the checkmark next to it.